# Moon countries?

Tags: international-law, territory, space

We are about to colonize the moon. One of Nasa's officials warns about China potentially claiming territory of the Moon. Since the Moon is by definition not part of the Earth, shouldn't all countries have their own territory on it?

Answer (score 2):

> We are about to colonize the moon.

If by "we" you mean the United States, then yes and no. The ultimate goal of the Artemis program is to establish a colony on the moon, but this does not constitute [colonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonization) in the traditional sense of the word in that the US will not claim ownership of the land the colony sits on. The colony would be something more akin to the International Space Station, which is not owned or governed by any sovereign state.

> One of Nasa's officials warns about China potentially claiming territory of the Moon.

Both the United States and China are members of the [Outer Space Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty) of 1967, which forbids any nation from claiming territory on the Moon. If either of them did claim any such territory, they would be violating the treaty, and I doubt that any other nations would acknowledge their claim.

> Since the Moon is by definition not part of the Earth, shouldn't all countries have their own territory on it?

I don't see why they should. As I mentioned above, owning territory on the Moon is forbidden by the Outer Space Treaty and, while not every country in the world is a signatory to it, I have no reason to believe that any such claims by non-signatories would be taken seriously. Besides, what good would a territory on the moon be to non-spacefaring nations like Zimbabwe? They wouldn't be able to access it.